# iphone+webservice

Tags: iphone, web-services, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have one web service but when i pass multiple word like new erra it will return 0 bytes in NSMutuabledata 
my method is like

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?url='%@'&word=%@",apiUrl,self.urlString,searchword];
NSMutableData *Data = [appDelegate initRequestWithPost:url withPostData:nil];
```

where searchword is new era
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you know how this site works, but If you don't mark any answer in your posts as accepted, people will ignore you in later posts. I don't want you to accept my post if it wasn't useful for you but guys like me are spending some of them time answering question just for a click. I think that is not so expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to escape the url string. Try using somthing like this.

```
+(NSString *)escapeURL:(NSString *)text{
CFStringRef tmp=CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                        NULL,
                                                        (CFStringRef)text,
                                                        NULL,
                                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)tmp;
return encodedString;
```

}